# Unmarshal time in custom format without any escape to heap (go1.19)

Tags: json, go

**go1.19** - relevant version for this question.

I believe, I need custom UnmarshalJSON, because I get time in a custom format.

My custom UnmarshalJSON has variable that escapes to heap. As far as I understand, it happens because of time.Parse() function. *I don't want this to happen because I'm gonna unmarshal a lot of objects, and I don't think it is a good way to leave like that.*

Is there any way to get rid of `string(b)` escaping to heap?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const customTimeLayout = "02-01-2006 15:04"

type customTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (ct *customTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    s := string(b) // escapes to heap

    s = strings.Trim(s, "\"")

    t, err := time.Parse(customTimeLayout, s)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to parse time: %w", err)
    }

    ct.Time = t

    return nil
}

func main() {
    jsonData := []byte("\"31-12-2022 16:00\"")

    var unmarshalled customTime
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &unmarshalled)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just wait for Go 1.20. It does not escape under go1.20rc1.

Otherwise.. I would recommend benchmarking first. It is unlikely the allocation would be significant overall. Eg, `time.Parse` (and `encoding/json` in general) likely has a larger performance impact.

`time.Parse` could be replaced with custom conversion code if performance must be improved. Something like:

```golang
var errInvalid = errors.New("invalid")

func parseTimestamp(s string) (time.Time, error) {
    if len(s) != 16 || s[2] != '-' || s[5] != '-' || s[10] != ' ' || s[13] != ':' {
        return time.Time{}, errInvalid
    }
    var errAtoi error
    atoi := func(num string) int {
        n, err := strconv.Atoi(num)
        if errAtoi == nil {
            errAtoi = err
        }
        return n
    }

    day := atoi(s[:2])
    month := time.Month(atoi(s[3:5]))
    year := atoi(s[6:10])
    hour := atoi(s[11:13])
    minute := atoi(s[14:16])
    if errAtoi != nil {
        return time.Time{}, errAtoi
    }

    return time.Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0, time.UTC), nil
}
```

Note: the string will still escape before Go 1.20. If you academically interested in how to avoid the heap escape. You could:

- Copy to a preallocated buffer first (eg, `sync.Pool` so it is goroutine safe, or a global `[]byte` protected via `sync.Mutex`). This buffer is effectively heap allocated once which avoids the per call allocation.
- Implement your own `atoi` function that operates on `[]byte` to avoid the string conversion escape. Alternatively you can use the `unsafe` package to interpret a `[]byte` as a `string` while avoiding the allocation/copy so it can be used with `strconv.Atoi`.

However, this extra effort to avoid the allocation pre-Go1.20 is unlikely to provide any practical improvement. I wouldn't recommend it.